# apt-cache search <package> doesn't detected package built from source and installed using dpkg -i

Tags: apt, deb, source

Because I wanted to install some packages after building them with g++-4.9, I did:

```
/usr/local/src $ sudo apt-get source --compile libmysql++3

/usr/local/src $ sudo apt-get souce --compile liblucene++
```

Then I installed the resulting .debs, of which there were seven:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i liblucene++0_3.0.4-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

However, when I search for them

```
$ apt-cache search liblucene++0
```

they don't show up, and when I did

```
$sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude full-upgrade
```

it said there were newer versions? Why couldn't apt-cache detect them, and why were "newer" versions (they seems to be the same version) then installed?

Comment: If you package build from existing Ubuntu repo sources then you've created the exact same package name/version. Repo packages are then considered upgrades. You need to create a new debian/changelog entry & slightly increase the package version. To what depends on the current version naming, generally best to set above current but below any future update that may come along. That way you're informed of a newer package which could be security related.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to list `liblucene` (`liblucene++0`) relevant packages run:

```
apt-cache search liblucene
```

or:

```
apt-cache search liblucene++0*
```

if you want to check package `liblucene++0` run:

```
apt-cache policy liblucene++0
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd never heard of "apt-cache policy". That will prove useful in the future.